# Comparing variation of two datasets of dimensionless quantities

Tags: variance, coefficient-of-variation

I have a biological dataset in which we measured two dimensionless quantities $x$ and $y$. Let $X = \{x_1,\dots,x_N\}$ and $Y = \{y_1,\dots, y_N\}$ be the vectors holding this data. I want to argue that $x$ varies less than $y$, which is evident when I plot $X/ \overline{X}$ and $Y/ \overline{Y}$.

To quantify this, I calculated the coefficient of variation $v_X = s_X/\overline{X}$ where $s_X$ is the standard deviation for $X$ and $Y$ and saw that $v_X<v_Y$.

However, someone has pointed out to me that since $x$ and $y$ are dimensionless, the quantities $x$ and $1/y$ encode the same information. When I use the dataset $1/Y = \{1/y_1,\dots,1/y_N\}$, we see that $v_{1/Y}<v_X$. My argument that $X$ is better than $Y$ since $X$ "varies less" than $Y$ breaks down.

Is there an alternate, more accepted approach to compare the variation between datasets of dimensionless quantities?